# convex square - matlab

Tags: octave, matlab

Given an interactive input of 4 points marked clockwise with the mouse pointer, I need to check using Matlab whether the shape that was drawn is a quadrilateral convex or not. I saw some people that suggested a gift wrapping algorithm. My thought was just using `tan`, such that if I have an angle greater than 180 degrees, the shape is not a convex. 
Can you suggest a better way to do it? I'd appreciate your reference to following code:

```
showImage(imageA)
hold on 
% Initially, the list of points is empty.
xy = [];
n = 0;
% Loop, picking up the points.
disp('Please enter corners of place to insert image in clockwise order.')

for i = 1:4
[xi,yi] = ginput(1);
plot(xi,yi,'yo')
xy(:,i) = [xi;yi];
end

%check if this is a convex quadrillateral
a1 = ( xy(2,2) - xy(2,1) ) / ( xy(1,2)  - xy(1,1) );
a2 = ( xy(2,3) - xy(2,2) ) / ( xy(1,3)  - xy(1,2) ); 
a3 = ( xy(2,4) - xy(2,3) ) / ( xy(1,4)  - xy(1,3) );
a4 = ( xy(2,1) - xy(2,4) ) / ( xy(1,1)  - xy(1,4) );

tan1 = abs( atand( (a2-a1) /( 1+a1*a2) ) );
tan2 = abs( atand( (a3-a2) / (1+a3*a2) ) );
tan3 = abs( atand( (a4-a3) / (1+a4*a3) ) );
tan4 = abs( atand( (a1-a4) / (1+a1*a4) ) );

if ((tan1 > 180) | (tan2 > 180) | (tan3 > 180) | (tan4 > 180))
disp('this is not a convex quadrillateral!!')
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by better? It should not be that hard to determine if four points in a 2d plane make a convex shape.

Comment: my idea was to use, tan() = m2-m1/(1+m1*m2). since i have 4 coordinates, i think this will be the easiest way.

Comment: can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code ? i have tried it over non-convex quadrillateral and i get an answer that it is a convex. i don't get degress greater than 180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very simple way to do it:

- Take all combinations of 3 points (there are 4 in total).
- Check if the fourth point is in the triangle defined by using  those points as corners.

If any of the fourth points is in the triangle it is not convex, otherwise it is.

I think this will work for n point in general, if you are prepared to do n+1 checks.

Comment: You can check if a point is inside a triangle by doing some basic cross product calculations. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51326/determining-if-an-arbitrary-point-lies-inside-a-triangle-defined-by-three-points